# I don't know how to query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table T1, with two columns  C1 and C2, in these columns there are numbers and they can be repeated.
sample:

```
C1 | C2
-------
10 | 8
11 | 8
12 | 10
10 | 2
11 | 10
14 | 2
```

I need to find the number of the column C1 that has the value of  8 and 2 in the column C2. In this case of the sample the query should return 10.
Have I explained? Can someone help me out?

Comment: In your example, the pairs are not repeated.

Comment: he said numbers can be repeated, not pairs, I think every c1 has a max occurence of 2

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be

```
select 
c1 from table_name
where c2 in (2,8)
group by c1
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: You need having count(DISTINCT c2) = 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT y.c1
FROM table_name x
JOIN table_name y
ON x.c1 = y.c1
WHERE (x.c2 = 8 AND y.c2 = 2) OR (x.c2 = 2 AND y.c2 = 8);
```

Comment: Distinct is not a function on a column, it works on the whole selected rows! Write SELECT DISTINCT y.c1 instead! (select distinct (c1), c2 eq. select distinct c1, c2 eq select distinct c1, (c2)...)

Comment: I did not know that, that would mean this will stop working as soon as you want to add your c2 for both rows, seeing as it will return both matches